# The probability of choosing a particular color combination of balls after five draws

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

[image: Simple probability question]

Sorry if this has been asked before, i can't get my head around how to take into account that the order of the balls being drawn is not important.

Comment: "Replaced" with what? Is it just put back into the box?

Comment: I guess the meaning is that the chosen ball is placed back in the box.

Answer (score 1):

This is a multinomial distribution.

The probability of drawing the balls in *a specific* order is: $(6/15)^3(4/15)(5/15)$

However, there are $5!/3!$ distinct orders to draw 3 blue, 1 red, and 1 white balls.

Thus the answer is: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B=3,R=1,W=1) & = \dbinom{5}{3,1,1}(\tfrac 6{15})^3(\tfrac 4{15})(\tfrac 5{15}) \\[1ex] & = \frac{128}{1125} \\[1ex] &= 0.113\overline{7}\end{align}$$